# Unirest is caching basic authentication information

Tags: java, httpclient, basic-authentication, unirest

We are calling backend 2 rest services (A, B) (GET method), these 2 services have different credentials (username and password), but we faced strange behavior:

1- if we called A first, authentication is successful, but if we called B, we will receive forbidden (authentication is failed)

Then we deploy application again and do this scenario:

2- Call B first, authentication is successful, but if we called A, we will receive forbidden (authentication is failed):

This is the sample code of calling backend services:

```
HttpResponse<String> resp;
        try {
            resp = Unirest.get(url)
                    .basicAuth(username,password).asString();
            String jsonstr = resp.getBody();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
```

any help?

Comment: I am seeing the exact same issue.  I wonder if we have to call .shutdown() between every call?  That would stink.

Comment: Hi, I'm working on a fork of Unirest and trying to fix all the issues. I found this one and I'm having problems replicating it. Mind looking at this test and let me know how it's different from what you are doing? https://github.com/OpenUnirest/unirest-java/commit/414720b38983900b6366bc77f01952113256d0f6

Comment: @ryber Good news, if you can help you, if you need

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that under the covers HTTP client is caching the JSESSIONID cookie.  I have switched to the OpenUnirest 2.2.08+ version of the library found here:  https://github.com/OpenUnirest/unirest-java

Now I can set the option to disable cookie management and now my basic auth caching problem is resolved.

```
Options.enableCookieManagement(false);
```

See Issue Ticket for more information: https://github.com/OpenUnirest/unirest-java/issues/30